# How are answer accepted questions that should be closed dealt with?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I'm looking at a question like [asp.net MVC response design best template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499548/asp-net-mvc-responsive-design-best-template) and thinking to myself it should be closed.  Is there a system in place to make sure answer accepted questions aren't ignored because they've been answered?

Comment: You can close even though it's answered

Comment: Agreed, but because they are answered, I would suspect most will drop off and become noise on searches way before they are closed.

Comment: @ErikPhilips A close vote is enough to put the question in the [close review queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/), and it will be closed eventually. However, a question being closed doesn't make it less of a noise on searches, it still shows up. So... use your delete votes as well ;)

Comment: Oh and hello @ErikPhilips - welcome to meta!

Comment: @Yannis your comment is actually the answer is it not?

Comment: @GeoffDalgas Hello! Hows the weather at SO? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is generally true that questions don't get much activity after they get an accepted answer, and this may lead in close worthy questions staying open for a while. However, it only takes one close vote for a question to enter the [Close Votes review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close), and when that happens it's almost guaranteed that it will get the attention it needs (eventually).

That said, if you feel a question - answered or not - should be closed as soon as possible, you always have the option of flagging for moderation attention and asking the moderators to intervene. This should be reserved for extreme cases, we generally don't want to call the moderators for stuff that the community should be handling by itself. One possible example where moderator intervention would be appropriate is when someone set a bounty to a close worthy question, as regular users can not vote to close a question with an active bounty.

Conversely, and since you mentioned searches in comments, closed questions still appear in searches. You may limit your searches to only open questions by using the `closed:0` search operator (and `closed:1` will only return closed questions). Since you recently passed the 10K reputation threshold, you can now also vote to delete closed questions (amongst [other things](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools)). It takes 3 votes minimum for a closed question to be deleted, and when that happens it won't appear in searches anymore. You might also want to start familiarizing yourself with the [10K tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools). The tools are not as nice as the review queues, but the list of pending delete votes can be very useful when scouting for questions to delete.